# Does PHP 5.4 work with Mysql 5.6? if yes, what is right way to install them in Centos 6

Tags: php, mysql

I have installed php 5.4 under Centos 6.8 (5.4 is required php version for Magento 1.8), when I install Mysql 5.6 by these commands

wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm

rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm

yum -y install mysql-server

at end of installation, I got below information:
[image]

I could not find a way to address this error by Google.  I am not sure about

- Does php5.4 work with Mysql5.6?
- Is the way I installed Mysql5.6 correct?
- why did this error happen?

Will appreciate if anyone can guide me a way out here, also explain the error.

Comment: `Does php5.4 work with Mysql5.6?`, yes it does. This seems more like a mysql question than a PHP question.

Comment: it is apparently php-mysql-5.4.45 not work with Mysql 5.6 lib (which was removed by installer)...and require a lib called libmysqlclient.so.18.  The big problem is these tools always leave error to user without providing solution.

Comment: if it does, then I would say either the tool is bad or I might use a wrong one.